# How can I display a docx file in the WebBrowser (WinForms) control?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control and if I call webBrowser.Navigate(url, "", null, null); it works great for images. But for a docx file it prompts me to download it instead of displaying it in the browser control.

How can I get it to display it?

thanks - dave

Comment: Have you tried navigating to a webpage that has it in an embed tag or an object tag?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/fce1efd4-4acf-4353-8b63-b92e36020052/open-a-microsoft-word-document-into-an-html-page-using-the-tag-object?forum=iewebdevelopment)

They talk about loading word as an activeX control on the page.

```
<script language="javascript">
     function openDoc() {
         var doc = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
         doc.visible = true;
         doc.Documents.Open("path.docx");
     } 
     opeDoc();
 </script>
```